# How to set credentials in AWS SDK v3 JavaScript?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I am scouring the documentation, and it only provides pseudo-code of the credentials for v3 (e.g. `const client = new S3Client(clientParams)`

How do I initialize an S3Client with the bucket and credentials to perform a getSignedUrl request? Any resources pointing me in the right direction would be most helpful. I've even searched YouTube, SO, etc and I can't find any specific info on v3. Even the documentation and examples doesn't provide the actual code to use credentials. Thanks!

As an aside, do I have to include the fake folder structure in the filename, or can I just use the actual filename? For example: bucket/folder1/folder2/uniqueFilename.zip or uniqueFilename.zip

Here's the code I have so far: (Keep in mind I was returning the `wasabiObjKey` to ensure I was getting the correct file name. I am. It's the client, GetObjectCommand, and getSignedUrl that I'm having issues with.

```js
exports.getPresignedUrl = functions.https.onCall(async (data, ctx) => {
  const wasabiObjKey = `${data.bucket_prefix ? `${data.bucket_prefix}/` : ''}${data.uid.replace(/-/g, '_').toLowerCase()}${data.variation ? `_${data.variation.replace(/\./g, '').toLowerCase()}` : ''}.zip`
  const { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3')
  const s3 = new S3Client({
    bucketEndpoint: functions.config().s3_bucket.name,
    region: functions.config().s3_bucket.region,
    credentials: {
      secretAccessKey: functions.config().s3.secret,
      accessKeyId: functions.config().s3.access_key
    }
  })
  const command = new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: functions.config().s3_bucket.name,
    Key: wasabiObjKey,
  })
  const { getSignedUrl } = require("@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner")
  const url = getSignedUrl(s3, command, { expiresIn: 60 })
  return wasabiObjKey
})
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is a credential chain that provides credentials to your API calls from the SDK
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html

> Loaded from AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) roles for Amazon
> EC2
>
> Loaded from the shared credentials file (~/.aws/credentials)
>
> Loaded from environment variables
>
> Loaded from a JSON file on disk
>
> Other credential-provider classes provided by the JavaScript SDK

You can embed the credential inside your source code but it's not the prefered way

```
new S3Client(configuration: S3ClientConfig): S3Client
```

Where S3ClientConfig contain a `credentials` property

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/modules/credentials.html

```js
    const { S3Client,GetObjectCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
    
    let client = new S3Client({
        region:'ap-southeast-1',
        credentials:{
            accessKeyId:'',
            secretAccessKey:''
        }
    });
    
    (async () => {
      const response = await client.send(new GetObjectCommand({Bucket:"BucketNameHere",Key:"ObjectNameHere"}));
      console.log(response);
    })();
```

Sample answer

```
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    requestId: undefined,
    extendedRequestId: '7kwrFkEp3lEnLU+OtxjrgdmS6gQmvPdbnqqR7I8P/rdFrUPBkdKYPYykWivuHPXCF1IHgjCIbe8=',
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
```

Comment: I was trying to dig up my code that I have. I'll post it to see where I'm going wrong. I have it in a firebase function (and I'm getting the credentials from the functions.config().fileName env vars.

Comment: Also, the link to your documentation is v2, not v3.

Comment: The credential chain does not change... Only the SDK syntax change from V2 to V3. That would affect only the last level of credential provider (Direct credential input from source code)

Comment: Why would they split the documentation like that?

Comment: Do you have to specify a bucket name for both S3Client *and* GetObjectCommand? I'm getting this error now:  `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No value provided for input HTTP label: Bucket.`

Comment: I am pretty sure that Bucket is required for GetObjectCommand

Comment: I am now getting the urls, but for some reason, the path is omitting the endpoint. (e.g. `https://edit-elements/cinematic_light/ambient_light_pack/ambient_light_pack_mp4.zip?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=LGM4T39ED9XR1H7ESCLM%2F20210706%2Fus-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210706T055432Z&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-Signature=6282eda73a65947195a928703ba3986e3690957d60ccfd39ab74b1fe89082c85&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&x-id=GetObject` There's no `https://s3.us-central-1.wasabisys.com/` before the link. Any ideas?

Comment: Since my question has branched off into another issue, I've marked this one as the answer for the OP, and I've created another question here. If you have any insight, I would appreciate it! -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68265652/getpresignedurl-does-not-attach-endpoint-w-region-to-url

Comment: It's terrible that on the npm website for this package they don't show you how to set the credentials. It is the basic thing you need to work with it.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a simple approach I use (in Deno) for testing (in case you don't want to go the signedUrl approach and just let the SDK do the heavy lifting for you):

```js
import { config as env } from 'https://deno.land/x/dotenv/mod.ts' // https://github.com/pietvanzoen/deno-dotenv
import { S3Client, ListObjectsV2Command } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/@aws-sdk/client-s3' // https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3

const {AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} = env()

// https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/modules/credentials.html
const credentials = {
    accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
}

// https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/interfaces/s3clientconfig.html
const config = {
    region: 'ap-southeast-1',
    credentials,
}

// https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/s3client.html
const client = new S3Client(config)

export async function list() {
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/interfaces/listobjectsv2commandinput.html
    const input = {
        Bucket: 'BucketNameHere'
    }

    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/command.html
    const cmd = new ListObjectsV2Command(input)
    
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/listobjectsv2command.html
    return await client.send(cmd)
}
```

Comment: This is great. I was able to use this pattern to work with the Bedrock SDK with the aws js-sdk v3.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is basically the same as what's been said above, but for anyone who's migrating from v2 to v3 and **not** moving to the new modular model, you will find that your existing clients don't immediately work, because the expected credentials format is different. If you previously had…

```js
new AWS.CloudWatch({
    apiVersion: '2010-08-01',
    region: event.region,
    credentials: new AWS.Credentials(
        role.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
        role.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
        role.Credentials.SessionToken,
    )
})
```

…you'll have to replace `new AWS.Credentials` with an object:

```js
new CloudWatch({
    apiVersion: '2010-08-01',
    region: event.region,
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: role.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: role.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
        sessionToken: role.Credentials.SessionToken,
    },
  });
```