# getPresignedUrl does not attach endpoint w/ region to url in Wasabi

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, wasabi-hot-cloud-storage

I am trying to generate a presignedUrl for objects in a **Wasabi** bucket (not the actual Amazon S3) using the S3 API. I have it generating the URL, but for some reason, it's not adding the region/endpoint to the URL.

So, instead of `https://s3.us-central-1.wasabisys.com/bucket/filepath` I get `https://bucket/filepath`

Here is my code:

```
exports.getPresignedUrl = functions.https.onCall(async (data, ctx) => {
  const wasabiObjKey = `${data.bucket_prefix ? `${data.bucket_prefix}/` : ''}${data.uid.replace(/-/g, '_').toLowerCase()}/${data.uid.replace(/-/g, '_').toLowerCase()}${data.variation ? `_${data.variation.replace(/\./g, '').toLowerCase()}` : ''}.zip`
  const { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3')
  const s3 = new S3Client({
    bucketEndpoint: ee_products_bucket_endpoint,
    region: functions.config().s3_bucket.region,
    credentials: {
      secretAccessKey: functions.config().s3.secret,
      accessKeyId: functions.config().s3.access_key
    }
  })
  const command = new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: functions.config().s3_bucket.name,
    Key: wasabiObjKey,
  })
  const { getSignedUrl } = require("@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner")
  try {
    const url = getSignedUrl(s3, command, { expiresIn: 60 })
    return url
  }
  catch(err) {
    return `Error: ${err}`
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you clarify what's wrong? The url format should be `https://your-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/?rest...`. So what exactly is wrong with your url?

Comment: I'll give you a sample: `https://edit-elements/cinematic_light/ambient_light_pack/ambient_light_pack_h264.zip?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=LGM4T39ED9XR1H7ESCLM%2F20210706%2Fus-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210706T064723Z&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-Signature=51fe32276ac405adfb5c0f16204acd4b3d24c1cebdcc9dca6734fd8efd532fc7&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&x-id=GetObject`

There's no region or prefix anywhere. It's just edit-elements/file

Comment: I should clarify that I'm using wasabi and *not* actual amazon, so they specify this endpoint for my bucket's region: `https://s3.us-central-1.wasabisys.com`

Comment: But does it work?

Comment: It does not. It says there's a typo in the address. I'll make one that lasts for an hour, and I'll post it here so you can see.

Comment: Here's one that's good for an hour: `https://edit-elements/cinematic_light/ambient_light_pack/ambient_light_pack_h264.zip?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=LGM4T39ED9XR1H7ESCLM%2F20210706%2Fus-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210706T065052Z&X-Amz-Expires=216000&X-Amz-Signature=762e8805c9ad8d1558a063678726344f5c98a17b302becc2c0e2367aa01f0e49&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&x-id=GetObject`

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the solution, and it was that `functions.config().s3_bucket.endpoint` was present *online* - but I didn't deploy it to the .runtimeconfig.json in my emulators, so the string was null.

The command to env vars locally to test:

Windows:

```
firebase functions:config:get | ac .runtimeconfig.json
```

OSX:

```
firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json
```