# @aws-sdk/client-s3: Setting S3Client config in code: "AWS Access Key Id not exists"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Goal: Set AWS IAM credentials to S3Client config directly in code.

Initial Reference: [How to set credentials in AWS SDK v3 JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68264237/how-to-set-credentials-in-aws-sdk-v3-javascript)

Using [@aws-sdk/client-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-s3), can perform `S3Client` requests using AWS credential keys from environment:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=ASIA*****HM7
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=aXH*****R+4
```

Note: `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` is an `ASIA` Temporary (AWS STS)

Providing only `"region"` to `S3Client` config to request a listing of buckets:

```
const s3Config: {
  region: 'us-west-2'
};

const s3Client = new S3Client(s3Config);
```

Successful response:

```
ListBucketsCommandOutput:
  "Buckets": [
    {
      "Name": "my-bucket"
    }
  ]
```

However, pulling the same AWS credential keys from local environment and assigning as `"credentials"` to `S3Client` config, it errors `"AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist"`

**Code importing AWS keys for S3Client create:**

```
const s3Config: {
  region: 'us-west-2',
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  },
};

const s3Client = new S3Client(s3Config);
```

**Code Error Response:**

```
{
  "success": false,
  "error": "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records."
}
```

How can this be corrected?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IAM User credentials have 2 parts:

1. AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (format: `AKIA...`)
2. AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

STS credentials have 3 parts:

1. AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (format: `ASIA...`)
2. AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
3. AWS_SESSION_TOKEN

You indicated an STS access key but you did not also include AWS_SESSION_TOKEN, so I suspect that IAM thinks that you are providing IAM User credentials and so it attempts to lookup `ASIA...` in its database. It fails to find the access key because `ASIA...` is not actually an IAM User access key and authentication fails with:

> AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist

To fix, indicate the session token when creating your client. Or switch to IAM User credentials, but be aware that IAM User credentials are not a [best security practice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#bp-workloads-use-roles) because they are long-lived whereas STS credentials are short-lived.

Details of the AWS key formats such as `AKIA...`, `ASIA...` can be found [here](https://awsteele.com/blog/2020/09/26/aws-access-key-format.html).

Comment: @jarmon Thank you for your response. I was able to resolve this when I switched from SSO credentials (ASIA) to IAM credentials (AKIA).